# Improvement on djikstra's algorithm for shortest paths

Tags: algorithms, graphs, data-structures

We all know about the djikstra's algorithm for computing single source shortest path and the complexity for the same as ***O(m log n)*** 
( m being the number of edges and n the number of vertices ), this complexity results from using the heap as a data structure for the algorithm

However I recently came across a statement which says this complexity can be improved to ***O( m + n log n)*** by using another exotic type of heap as a data structure. Does anyone has any idea about this data structure which is being mentioned?.

Comment: Fibonacci heap.

Comment: Since even Wikipedia has answers both [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue#Specialized_heaps) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Running_time), I think you did not do enough research before asking here. Does your question go beyond what is written there?

Comment: @Raphael wasn't sure where to start i was mostly following djikstra's algorithm however these comments should get me started . Thanks.

Comment: I do believe @NP-hard should have marked his comment as an aswer since that is the correct answer. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm